# Do I need IPN for processing preapproved payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm aware that it's necessary to use IPNs for single payments (situations when the user approves the payment and than closes the browser etc.), but am not sure weather I need them for preapproved payments, since the whole thing is done in a single request. **The question goes: can I rely that a preapproved payment's response is final, or do I need to use IPNs for that too?**

I tried to find some kind of explanation of the whole transaction process, but without success. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the response from PayPal support:

> It is possible that a payment status can be changed, for instance if a
>   payment was disputed then its possible that a payment could be
>   reversed. In this case you should handle IPN's for payments as it
>   assures that your system always has the latest status on any payment.

Seems like IPN handling is inevitable.

@Andrew thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The API call response is final, yes, unless the payment is in a pending status for any reason.  Then the API result would be success but the payment status would be pending.  If you're using IPN you'd get one notification for the pending payment and another when it clears so you can automate things accordingly.

The API response also won't contain as much detail as the IPN would, so you may need IPN to obtain data that isn't available in the API response.

IPN is never required.  It's just very useful and often recommended.